# DHCP searching wrong network

Tags: dhcp

I have a stand-alone device with no console. It's searching for DHCP address on 192.168.1.1/24 while my network router serves DHCP for 192.168.0.1/24. Thus, the device is not getting assigned an IP address, and without a console there is no way to login to it other than network. So, im stuck wondering how to gain access. Any suggestions?

Comment: Exactly what is this device? Why do you believe it is "searching for DHCP address on 192.168.1.1/24"?

Comment: DHCP is a broadcast, so the client shouldn't have the ability to search on a specific network.  It's essentially yelling "Hey! Someone out there give me an IP address!"  Can you post info about how you came to the conclusion that it's searching a specific net?  Are you watching traffic with Wireshark or something?

Comment: I plugged in the device and it will not connect to my DHCP server. The seller told me it was previously working on 192.158.1.1/24.

Comment: My guess is the device has a static assigned ip address for the network it was previously connected to. If it were me, I'd reset it to it's factory default settings.

Comment: Probably was on a static address. I ended up downloading a new copy of the OS onto a stick and overwrote the previous SD card, now it comes up properly.